# Create a query on multiple tables yii

Tags: php, yii

What is the equivalent code in Yii?

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc)
{
echo $row['id']." ".getSkillById($row['skillId']);
}  

function getSkillById($id)  
{
$sql = mysql_query("select * from `skills` WHERE id = '$id'");
$res = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql);
return $res['skill_label'];
}
```

How can something be implemented in yii?
Is this standard procedure?

Answer (score 2):

`ActiveRecord` approche:

First, Create your model by using `GII`. for example your model name is: `Skill`. Now:

```
$skills=Skill::findAll();
if(!is_null($skills)){
   foreach($skiils as $skill){
        echo $skill->id;
   }
}
```

To get an skill by ID:

```
$skill=Skill::findByPk($id);
$skill->id; // Gets the skill ID
```

Woww, Don't you know Yii's `AR` supports `Relations`? Assume that you have a `User` table that each user has an skill id. So you must create `User` model. then in your `relation()` method of your user model you must write:

```
array('skill'=>array(self::HAS_ONE,'Skill','skill_id'));
```

All above are based on assumption. (AS YOUR QUESTION IS A LITTLE BROAD).Now, You can access to your users and their's skill by:

```
$users=User::findAll();
if(!is_null($users)){
   foreach($users as $user){
        echo $user->id; // USER IS
        echo $user->skill->id; // USER SKILL ID
   }
}
```

Another approach is using `Yii's query builder` like below:

```
$db=Yii::app()->db;
$skills=$db->createCommand('SELECT * FROM tbl_skills')->queryAll();
// A LOOP
// foreach($skills as $skill) -> now the result is an associate array.
```

As a suggestion, first read carefully about Yii's `ORM` (`AR`) and Yii's `Query Builder`. Best place to find useful information is Yii's official document:

[Active Record](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.ar)

[Query Builder](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.query-builder)

Comment: Relations is a best method ,but i can't use it,because i am using "query builder"

Comment: So you can use `Join` in query builder or write your sql in query builder with a JOIN and use it easily